# animate vs css - animate is not working

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to use an animation effect but it's not working

This is working

```
$("#add-widgets").click(function () {
    $("#list-widgets").css({display:"block"});
});
```

But this is not:

```
$("#add-widgets").click(function () {
    $("#list-widgets").animate({display:"block"},1000);
});
```

Can you help me? 
Thanks

Comment: `display:block` is a binary function..it's either on or off. You can't animate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of animations you can use. It depends what you want. For example, for `fadeIn` you can use:

```
$("#list-widgets").fadeIn();
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't remember that function. Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate the display property because there are no in between values between these properties. For instance, an element can be set to `display:none` or any other property such as `display:block` but there is no value in between. If you would animate opacity from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` then you have in between values such as `opacity:0.01` all the way to `opacity:0.99`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply make an "animation" from hidden to block:

```
$("#list-widgets").fadeIn();
```

Otherwise you should make an hack:

- Make a clone of your list:

  var tmp = $("#list-widgets").clone();
- Give to tmp new value with css:

  tmp.css({display:"block"});
- Save new top and left position:

  var newTop = tmp.position().top;
  var newLeft = tmp.position().left;
- Finally move your element:

  $("#list-widgets").animate({
    'top' : newTop,
    'left': newLeft
  },1000);